# Defining a variable inside of function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a huge newbie in python, I just started learning yesterday. This is actually my first project on python to resemble the Pythagorean theorem. When I run the code, I get a `NameError: name 'variabel' is not defined` error. This is my following code :

```
# Functions
def pythagoras_hypotenuse(variabel, variabel2) :
    answer = (variabel**2 + variabel2**2)**0.5
    return print("The length of the side is " + str(answer))

def pythagoras_sides(variabel, variabel2) :
    variabel = int(input("Enter the first side = "))
    variabel2 = int(input("Enter the second side = "))
    if variabel > variabel2 :
        return print("The length of the side is" + (variabel**2 - variabel2**2)**0.5)
    else :
        return print("The length of the side is" + (variabel2**2 - variabel**2)**0.5)

# A prompt to decide whether it's Hypotenuse or Sides
hypotenuse = input("Are you looking for hypotenuse? \nPlease respond with yes or no : ")
if hypotenuse == 'yes':
    pythagoras_hypotenuse(variabel, variabel2)
elif hypotenuse == 'no' :
    pythagoras_sides(variabel, variabel2)
else :
    print("Please respond with yes or no")

# Variables

variabel = int(input("Enter the first side = "))
variabel2 = int(input("Enter the second side = "))
```

Is there a way to define the variable instead of asking it in the first place? I want the code to kick things off with the hypotenuse or side prompt then you get to enter the sides/hypotenuse integers. My code is very messy, further explanations and advice will absolutely make my day. Many thanks!
Note: English is not my first language, sorry for the bad English!

Comment: if you wish to define the variable instead of asking, just do ```variabel = <some number>```.  If you're trying to get the user's response, then you need to move the ```variabel = int(...)``` and ```variabel2 = int()``` lines before the ```hypotenuse = input(...)``` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study python more because your code is too messy and the logic is unclear. Moreover, the word you tried to use is `variable` not `variabel`, I guess. The problem you are facing is just because of the flow of execution and improper use of the scope. However, a better clean approach is as follows

```py
def get_side_inputs():
    return int(input("\nEnter the first side: ")), int(input("\nEnter the second side: "))

def get_user_choice():
    return input("\nAre you looking for hypotenuse? \nPlease respond with yes or no : ")

def pythagoras_hypotenuse(variable, variable2):
    answer = (variabel**2 + variabel2**2)**0.5
    print("\nThe length of the side is " + str(answer))

def pythagoras_sides(variable, variable2):
    if variable > variable2:
        print("\nThe length of the side is", (variable**2 - variable2**2)**0.5)
    else :
        print("The length of the side is", (variable2**2 - variable**2)**0.5)

def main():

    first_side, second_side = get_side_inputs()

    choice = get_user_choice()

    if choice == "yes":
        pythagoras_hypotenuse(first_side, second_side)
    
    elif choice == "no":
        pythagoras_sides(first_side, second_side)
    
    else: 
        print("Please respond with yes or no!!")

main()
```

Few tips:

- Try to use the `main` method as a guide to your code. Anybody should understand the flow of your code by just looking the main method
- Name the variables properly
- Use whitespace and blank lines properly to make your code less messy

Comment: "Moreover, the word is variable not variabel", who asked for this correction?
This is not English :P

Comment: No one. Anybody can use anything as variables. But the use of descriptive and proper names are always better.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I was working the code with my native language then i had to shift it into English so I could post it here and inadvertently I missed a spot haha. I'll look more into 'main()' method, for now I'm still digging new things to discover on python. Again, thank you!

Comment: "But the use of descriptive and proper names are always better.", yeah I do agree with this but let that be upto the user :)

Comment: @AzarelGrahanditoAdi There is nothing extra about `main()`. In python, `main` is as same as any other function. If you have ever used languages like C or Java then you might understand how important is main. In python, it is not mandatory to use main but you can use it to guide whoever is reading your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Put the variable definition above when you ask for hypotenuse, with some dummy values:

```py
...other code...

variabel = 3
variabel2 = 4

# A prompt to decide whether it's Hypotenuse or Sides
hypotenuse = input("Are you looking for hypotenuse? \nPlease respond with yes or no : ")
if hypotenuse == 'yes':
    pythagoras_hypotenuse(variabel, variabel2)
elif hypotenuse == 'no' :
    pythagoras_sides(variabel, variabel2)
else :
    print("Please respond with yes or no")

# Variables

variabel = int(input("Enter the first side = "))
variabel2 = int(input("Enter the second side = "))
```

Answer (score 0):

So what are you trying to accomplish is — declaring an uninitalized variable, which is not possible for Python becuase of its syntax.

```js
var variabel1;  // value defaults to 'undefined'
```

the Pythonic equivalent to this is:

```py
variabel1 = None
```